# Where can I get an opinion?

Tags: discussion

I want to see developers' opinions on the use of a certain language feature, where is the right place to ask that question?

Comment: Do you really just want random opinions, or do you want well-reasoned, explained, and fact-based opinions? Do you want to know, "can I use X to do Y?" or just, "what do you think of Z?"

Comment: For which language?

Comment: see: **[Where can I ask questions that aren't Stack Overflow questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-stack-overflow-questions)**

Answer (score 16):

On Stack Exchange!

Not on Stack Exchange!

Let me explain. No, [let the FAQ explain](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

**Good**: *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face*. "I'm designing a plugin system with X, Y, and Z features. Based on  these requirements, would I be better off basing my system around interfaces or abstract classes, and why?"

**Bad**: *every answer is equally valid*. "Are interfaces better than abstract classes?"

**Ugly**: *it is a rant disguised as a question*. "Interfaces suck, amirite?"

Comment: +1. ... No, -1 .... No,  +1 :P

Comment: Um, yeah, I noticed that, @Manish...

Comment: I was checking was some spelling mistake in it :P

Answer (score 13):

You can try an appropriate chat room.

Answer (score 6):

### Not on the main sites

These sites are not for gathering opinions--they are for clear, definitive answers. asking on the appropriate chat is fine.

On the other hand, if you modified your question to a "what are the pros and cons of feature X" (which would be on topic), and formed your own opinion based on the answers, I think you'd have better results.

Comment: Asking for a list, isn't that frowned upon?

Comment: @mrl I don't think that's the case for a definitive list that would be limited to a few items. "Good books to learn c#"--bad. "What are the pros and cons of eval()"--good (I think)