# Where I can find opinions and advices to my posts, if they are considered inconstructive on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions

Recently some of my questions were cancelled, for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446139/how-difficult-is-javascript-html5-css-in-comparison-to-android

But I still need to resolve these problems. My question may be bad due to lack of knowledge. Where I can seek for a mature advice? At least what should I read before starting to ask such questions.

Comment: Have you read the FAQ? http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Before you were allowed to ask any questions, you were presented with [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice), which you must have explicitly agreed to ("thanks, I will keep these tips in mind when asking"). That page contains advice and links to other places with more advice. Did you read before clicking?

Comment: There's definitely irony in here somewhere

Comment: They're not closed because of your lack of knowledge. They're closed because Stack Overflow is the wrong place for this kind of questions. Those subjective questions asking for a collection of other's opinions can impossibly have a single technical and objective answer which is acceptable by everyone now and in the future. You need to look for a discussion forum instead of a Q&A site.

Comment: use chat as suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138621/165773)

Comment: [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> https://stackoverflow.com/q/13446139/102937

See here: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

> https://stackoverflow.com/q/13442946/102937

This is essentially a request for someone to do your work for you.  Do some research of your own, write some code of your own, and ask a question on Stack Overflow if you get stuck, showing your research and code.

See also http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476004/where-i-can-find-opinions-and-advices-to-my-posts-if-they-are-considered-incons

Posted to the wrong site.